# How to use convexity in this step?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to fill in the details of a proof about the following statement:

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function, if subdifferential of $f$ at $x$ is singleton, then $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

---

In the proof, the notes suppose $\partial f(x)=\{p\}$, and consider $g(v)=f(x+v)-f(x)-<p,v>$ for all $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Clearly $g$ is convex, $g\ge 0$ and $g(0)=0$. Using this,  he shows $\partial g(0)=\{0\}$.

Then the notes tried to show $g$ is differentiable at $0$. It first shows $\forall d\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\lim_{\lambda\to 0+}\frac{g(\lambda d)}{\lambda}$ exists. Then it aims to prove $\lim_{\lambda\to 0+}\frac{g(\lambda d)}{\lambda}=0,\quad\forall d\in\mathbb{R}^n$ using contradiction.

That is, suppose $\exists d\in \mathbb{R}^n, \lim_{\lambda\to 0+}\frac{g(\lambda d)}{\lambda}=\alpha\not=0$, then let $u=\frac{\alpha d}{\|d\|}\not=0$, he managed to show $g(\lambda d)\ge <u,\lambda d>,g(-\lambda d)\ge <u,-\lambda d>,\forall \lambda>0$ Also $\forall e\perp d, g(\lambda e)\ge 0=<u,\lambda e>,\forall \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then the notes says "**by convexity of $g$, $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n, g(y)\ge <u,y>$"**.

I am not sure how to use convexity of $g$ to derive the desired result in the last step.

Comment: I wonder where this came from? :-)

Comment: Meta comment: inner products use the `\langle` and `\rangle` symbols in LaTeX: $\langle x, y \rangle$

Comment: @MichaelGrant I found the same proof in an online notes of MIT and a master thesis of another university.

Comment: Great! It is good to have confirmation.

Comment: @MichaelGrant You may refer to [Theorem 1.17](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~pborwein/MITACS/papers/HamiltonThesis.pdf) in this thesis.

Answer (score 0):

You decompose $y$ on $d$ and $d^{\bot}$ : there exist $\lambda \in [0,1]$, $\mu \in \mathbb R$ and $e\in d^{\bot}$ such that

$$y = \frac{\lambda (\mu d)+ e}{1-\lambda}$$

ie

$$(1-\lambda)y + \lambda (-\mu d) = e$$

Then

$$g(e) = g( (1-\lambda)y + \lambda (-\mu d) ) \leq \lambda g( -\mu d) + (1-\lambda) g(y)$$

$$g(e) - \lambda g(-\mu d) \leq (1-\lambda) g(y)$$

$$<u,e> - \lambda <u,-\mu d> \leq (1-\lambda) g(y)$$

$$<u,e+ \lambda\mu d> \leq (1-\lambda) g(y)$$

$$<u,\frac{e+ \lambda\mu d}{1-\lambda}> \leq g(y)$$

$$<u,y> \leq g(y)$$

Comment: I just used the wrong inequality for convexity... oups -_-' I'll modify the proof

Comment: Modified it, hopefully, my brain didn't decide to do silly mistakes this time

Comment: May you give more details about how to get the third inequality? Thanks.